# Can I get just an XML representation from phpDocumentor 2

Tags: php, xml, phpdoc

Can I get just an XML representation of the parsed data from phpDocumentor 2? I have tried the checkstyle template and I only get the file names with no data. I would like to use the xml as a datasource that can be integrated into another site.

Checkstyle Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<checkstyle version="1.3.0">
  <file name="file1.php"/>
  <file name="file2.php"/>
  <file name="file3.php"/>
  ... etc ...
</checkstyle>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to get the xml file. This is what I did parsing the directories and getting the xml file.

```
phpdoc -d /path/to/src/ -t output-dir --template=xml
```

Comment: This is related to phpDocumenter (v1). `output` doesn't exist in phpDocumenter2 anymore.

Comment: Ha. Then I probably downloaded v1? Let me see.

Comment: @Pixelmonster Hm, you just confuses me. This is same as of v2. And your confusion was caused due to the -t parameter `output` which I mean output directory. I am going to edit this.

Comment: -t means the *transform parameter* and sets the directory for the transformer to the folder called output
on the other hand the *parameter output* could set the format of the generated output
That's the difference I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `phpdoc project:parse` runtime choice might give you what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the insight... Do you have an example. There is no documentation for the parse option http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/commands/project_parse.html

Comment: ```phpdoc project:parse -d src/ -t docs/``` should be enough args to run it.  I believe this produces the AST XML that ```project:transform``` would separately run against.

Comment: For me it only creates folders with .dat files for the incremental building.

Comment: Hmmm, I was thinking that the parse step made an XML "AST" file.  It might be that the internals have changed since ~2.0 and moved away from that.  I'd say get version 2.0 rather than newer versions, maybe even one of the 2.0 betas, and see if parse produces an XML artifact that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this website](http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/getting-started/changing-the-look-and-feel.html) which shows the use of a template in command line.

```
$ phpdoc -d "./src" -t "./docs/api" --template="checkstyle"
```

So if you want to export to xml simply run

```
$ phpdoc -d "./src" -t "./docs/api" --template="xml"
```

Tested.